# Changing the order of columns in a responsive 3-column layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to convert a 3-column fixed width layout to a responsive one and have been frying my brain trying to understand all the various ways people are going about this. The column widths are roughly 22% - 56% - 22% of the container div width. When displaying in a smartphone context, I want columns 1 and 3 to appear together side by side taking up 50% of the screen width each, then column 2 (the main content) to appear below at 100% of width.

Can anyone advise the best way to go about achieving this? Do I need to swap columns 2 and 3 around to get them to flow the way I want them to? Or is there another way that works as well without having to go through and change the markup of the entire site? I would like to use CSS only solutions if possible. Thanks.

Comment: A (simplified) example would help. Is this about a single-row layout table? That would be essentially simpler than dealing with a “real” table with multiple rows.

Comment: I use divs. So ...

<div id='container'>
    <div id='column-1'>22% width</div>
    <div id='column-2'>56% width</div>
    <div id='column-3'>22% width</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with media queries and floats. Using `float: left` and `float: right` you just need to set up your HTML properly. The trick is to float column 1 to the left and two and three to the right with three coming before two in your html:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/73rjh9km/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="one"></div>
   <div class="three"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
   float: left;
   background: red;
   width: 22%;
   height:100px; 
}

.two{
   float: right;
   background: blue;
   width: 56%;
   height:100px; 
}

.three{
   float: right;
   background: green;
   width: 22%;
   height:100px; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px){

   .one{
      width: 50%
   }

   .two{
      width: 100%
   }

   .three{
      width: 50%
   }

}
```

**UPDATE**

As Crispy-George posted you could use `flexbox` but it does have limited browser support and basically doesn't work with IE 9 and below:

[**FLEXBOX EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/73rjh9km/1/)

Comment: Yes. That's kind of how I imagined I might have to do it but wondered if there was a way without editing all the markup throughout the site, especially as I'm hoping to get away with leaving the fixed width site intact for screen widths 900px and over. Why is column 2 float:right though? I would have thought it would work with float:left?

Comment: @Caldoverde so `float: right` works depending on which item comes first, so in the HTML, column3 comes first, floats right, and then column 2 comes next and also floats right, which would stack it to the left of column 3 if that makes sense. If you're not worried about browser support you could use the `flexbox` method too. Updated Answer

Comment: Ach! Of course! Wasn't thinking that one through. Thanks.

Comment: You got it, the choice is up to you. Personally I would take having to do a little extra work and rearrange my HTML so i didnt lose out on browser support, but it depends on your target audience and flexbox is definitely convenient. If this answered your question do you mind checking it off as resolved?

Comment: You might be right there, though there could be an issue with the WordPress part of the site since column 3 = sidebar. So basically the choice is between reordering the columns or using flexbox? No other workarounds out there?

Comment: well you could always you javascript

Comment: I could, but the site uses quite a bit of javascript for its image handling. I'm wary of possible conflicts - I don't know enough javascript to sort that out.

Comment: Yeah then you're better off not doing that then

Answer (score 1):

If you have to maintain a strict order on your columns, like:

```
<div class='box box-1'>Small box</div>
<div class='box box-2'>Yeah, I'm the big box</div>
<div class='box box-3'>Even Smaller box</div>
```

you can use `flexbox` to change the `order` of these boxes on your desired screen resolutions, however I believe it has no support for lower than IE9, but if you dont have to support older browsers, check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzj0g12p/1/)**.

The markup:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='box box-1'>Small box</div>
    <div class='box box-2'>Yeah, I'm the big box</div>
    <div class='box box-3'>Even Smaller box</div>
</div>
```

And the css stuff:

```
.container{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}
.box{
    min-height: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.box-1{
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
}
.box-2{
    width: 60%;
    background: teal;
}
.box-3{
    width: 15%;
    background: cyan;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px){
    .box-1{
        -webkit-order: 1;
        -ms-order: 1;     
        order: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }  
    .box-3{
        -webkit-order: 2;
        -ms-order: 2;     
        order: 2;
        width: 50%;
    } 
    .box-2{
        -webkit-order: 3;
        -ms-order: 3;     
        order: 3;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. The IE9 limitation ... hmmm ... well it may be we can live with that. I'd prefer IE8 to be supported but not really concerned beyond that.

Comment: Just a quick general question about the html/css here ... I've noticed while investigating responsive layouts that everyone seems to use classes rather than ids for column divs. It was always my practice to use ids for non-repeating elements in a layout. What's the rationale for classes?

Comment: @Caldoverde well I personally use ids when I need some js hooks or something like that; I stick with classes just in case, maybe I'll repeat them in some way later on, or chain more classes together, and overwriting some rules, and not worry about specificity issues or whatever issues may come from using ids